# How do I change my readline path?

Tags: python, libreadline

I'm trying to install ipython, which appears to require the readline library.

I did install readline via easy_install. But every test I run iptest (or any other file) it spits this back:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /bitnami/djangostack-osx-x86/output/common/lib/libreadline.5.2.dylib
>
> > Referenced from: /Users/bwareham/DjangoStack/python/bin/.python2.6.bin
> >
> > Reason: image not found
>
> Trace/BPT trap

I hunted around and found the libreadline.5.2.dylib at /DjangoStack/common/lib/libreadline.5.2.dylib

I figured I had a path problem, so I looked at the referenced file in the error message (/Users/bwareham/DjangoStack/python/bin/.python2.6.bin), which pointed me to . /Users/bwareham/DjangoStack/scripts/setenv.sh

That .sh file doesn't set any paths to /bitnami/djangostack-osx-x86/output/ so I don't know why it keeps looking for libreadline.5.2.dylib in that path.

How can I get it to look in the right place? Or do I have some other kind of problem?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `echo $PYTHONPATH` here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem by running `. <installdir>/scripts/setenv.sh`

Read the thread on https://community.bitnami.com/t/using-pip-with-bitnami-djangostack/7346/7